# laravel query retun object instead of string

Tags: php

I wrote this query to get string `type(value)`, which is up or down, instead it returns me an object.

```
    $o_response = $this->statuses()
     ->where('status_id', $o_health_status->id)
     ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
     ->select('values')
     ->first();
```

this is the result :

```
{"values":"up","pivot":{"notification_id":1,"status_id":1,"values":"up","created_at":"2016-11-04 13:18:29","updated_at":"2016-11-04 13:18:29"}}
```

It returns an object instead of string. Why?

Comment: i was expecting to get a string vsalue which is up or down, instead iam getting the whole object. what should i change?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Laravel eloquent returns collection ex.->get() or object ex. ->first() .

So i think you will need just to get column something like

$o_response = $o_response->values;

Comment: i would like to appreciate for the quick and perfect replay. it works for me. tnx